# Bootstrap change navbar icon color depending on background of section (better without Js)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, parallax

I have my [page](http://edwardbattistini.com) using bootstrap 3.1.1. My navbar is transparent and uses font-awesome icons and they are white as the background is blue on my landing section. The next section will be my resume (click on university icon) and I use a white background.

My problem is the icons of the navbar are now the same color as the background. How do I make them blue when they overlayed on white?

I've found [this](http://www.wickham43.net/iconcolorchange.php) but I don't know how to apply it with bootstrap.

EDIT :

My new idea is but can't find a way to code it :

- section 1 on level 1
- white icon Navbar on level level 2
- section 2 on level  3
- blue icon Navbar on level 4

My brain is going to explode

Comment: The solution you linked, requires you to repeat several DIV elements, which I believe is the only option if you really want a CSS only solution. Why no repeat them on each "page/scroll" and style them differently?

Comment: well if i understand you @Astuanax this would mean not fixed and while scrolling it could display two navbar ?

Comment: yes, if you want to go css only; while if you could use javascript/jQuery it not be so difficult to handle.